# ReactiveUI 6.5 - When ReactiveObject is inherited in class I get a build error Splat.dll could not be found

Tags: winforms, reactiveui, splat

I'm using Visual Studio 13 Community. Created a simple WinForms project, created an empty class and inherited ReactiveObject.  I've installed reactivui-winforms 6.5.0 using NuGet. I can see ver 1.0.0 was installed and Splat in references.

The code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ReactiveUI;
using Splat;

namespace ReactiveSplatTest
{
    class ReactiveObjectTest : ReactiveObject
    {
    }
}
```

In properties for the Splat reference the path is:

```
c:\users\rick reynolds\documents\visual studio 
2013\Projects\ReactiveSplatTest\packages\Splat.1.0.0\lib\Net45\Splat.dll
```

I have verified that this is the correct path. And that the file Splat.dll does exist there.

```
C:\Users\Rick Reynolds\Documents\Visual Studio 
2013\Projects\ReactiveSplatTest\packages\Splat.1.0.0\lib\Net45
```

I get this warning and error every time I build...

Warning 1:

```
Reference to type 'Splat.IEnableLogger' claims it is defined in 'c:\Users\Rick Reynolds\Documents\Visual Studio 
2013\Projects\ReactiveSplatTest\packages\Splat.1.0.0\lib\Net45\Splat.dll', 
but it could not be found   c:\Users\Rick Reynolds\Documents\Visual Studio 
2013\Projects\ReactiveSplatTest\packages\reactiveui-
core.6.5.0\lib\Net45\ReactiveUI.dll ReactiveSplatTest
```

Error 2:

```
The base class or interface 'Splat.IEnableLogger' in assembly 'Splat, 
Version=1.6.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' referenced by type 
'ReactiveUI.IReactiveObject' could not be resolved  c:\Users\Rick Reynolds\Documents\Visual Studio 
2013\Projects\ReactiveSplatTest\packages\reactiveui-
core.6.5.0\lib\Net45\ReactiveUI.dll ReactiveSplatTest
```

Comment: Never mind... I solved the issue. The wrong version of Splat was installed when ReactiveUI 6.5.0 was installed. It requires Splat 1.6.2 but 1.0.0 was installed. I found the correct version in NuGet, installed it and it's building correctly now.

Comment: Yes. It is a dependency bug: Has been fixed: https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/issues/928

Comment: Looks like it was finally fixed in 6.5.1 https://www.nuget.org/packages/reactiveui/6.5.1